# can we get null value using ResultSet getShort method in java

Tags: java, jdbc

Can one get `null` value using the `ResultSet.getShort()` method in java?
I know that it converts `null` value to `0`,and we can use the `getObject()` method to check `null` values, but can one get `null` values using the `getShort` method?

Comment: Of course not. How can a `short` be null?

Answer (score 2):

You could check that last fetched value was null or not using the resultset method wasNull(). If it was true you can consider your getShort() value is null instead of 0 in your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

> short getShort(String columnLabel) throws SQLException
>
> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a short in the Java programming language.
>
> Parameters: columnLabel - the label for the column specified with the
>   SQL AS clause. If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label
>   is the name of the column
>
> Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value
>   returned is 0
>
> Throws: SQLException - if the columnLabel is not valid; if a database
>   access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

Oracle Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getShort(java.lang.String)

So your answer is no, you can't get null from the getShort method.